# All good things are three (how to skip unwanted sub-matches?)

Tags: regex, perl

#### How to consume/skip unwanted matches?

Lets assume we have the following text:

```
my $t ='good good *bad !bad -bad "alwaysbad alwaysbad alwaysbad" good';
```

and I'd like to have a single regular expression that matches only `good` words. The real content of the symbolic words `good`, `bad`, and `alwaysbad` is, of course, `[0-9A-Za-z_@]+` (`\w+` is fine for this question). To tell a `bad` word from a `good` one, something like `(\s|^)\b\w` at the start of the word would suffice. Stuff in double quotes is always a bad word, even if not prefixed.

This is what I have:

```
my $r = qr/
           (?: " [^"]+ " )     # skip quoted part altogether, don't capture
            |                  # OR
           (?<!\S) \b ([\w@]+) # find words without 'bad' prefix and capture
          /x;
```

this expression would not capture the quoted part, but still match. Therefore, we'll have a `undefined` empty entry in the match list:

```
my @matches = $t =~ /$r/g;

print join "\n", @matches;

  good
  good
         <== (uninitialized value, this comes from the quoted part)
  good
```

Now the question:

Does anybody know a technique applicable to contemporary perl regular expressions **how to consume a given part of a string but not match it** with a single regex invocation?

The result should, therefore, be:

```
  good
  good
  good
```

---

**Addendum**:

Thanks to [Borodins answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11739976/170194), I see more clearly now. Just by removing the `|` (or) and applying any `or-zero-times` quantifier, it'll work:

```
my $r = qr/
           (?: " [^"]+ ")? \s?  # skip quotes + space if any
           (?<!\S) \b ([\w@]+)  # find words without 'bad' prefix and capture
          /x;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is only matching the non-capturing sequence because you have said that is what you wanted.

Write an optional prefix of any number of quoted strings with intervening non-quote characters, like this

```
my $r = qr/
  (?: " [^"]* " [^"]*?)*    # skip quoted part altogether, don't capture
  (?<!\S) \b (\w+)          # find words without 'bad' prefix and capture
/x;
```

But for clarity I would go for removing all quoted strings from the target before trying to match it. Don't forget that if you want to allow `@` as well in your substrings then you need `[\w@]`. And you also need a trailing check to make sure that there are no invalid characters *after* the beginning.

```
$t =~ s/"[^"]*"//g;
my @matches = $t =~ /(?:\s|^)[\w\@]+(?=\s|\z)/g;
```

Comment: O-o, I was completely dumbfolded by the quoted part. Of course, one can simply skip any well-defined part by applying the `*` quantifier to the whole sub-pattern. Time to do some more regex work again, hehe! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could just filter them out:

```
my @matches = grep { m/\S/ } $t =~ /$r/g;
```